# Applying CSS class to text

Tags: html, css, inheritance, media-queries

On my home page http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/ the text 'New South Wales', 'Victoria', 'Northern Territory', 'South Australia', 'Queensland', 'Travel Australia' How To Guides', 'Other Australia Blogs' should all be in bold and in the centre. This is how it has been for a long time, today I noticed this was no longer the case. I thought I had made a mistake on the page but then realised the issue had started occurring across the entire site.

The following code use to work.

```
<div class="BlackIcon">New South Wales</div>
<div class="BlackIcon">Victoria</div>
```

NOTE: You may need to click on the blue text to see the screenshot.

[The text 'New South Wales' is still associated with the CSS class 'BlackIcon' but now it is not inheriting the properties from the CSS class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJk0R.png)

```
/*To be used on its own, it has 100% width so you no longer need a guide css as well*/
@media screen and (max-width: 9999999px) {
    .BlackIcon {
        color: Black;
        background-color: White;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0 solid black;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your custom stylesheet has syntax errors.

Try pasting the entire style into a syntax checker of choice (http://csslint.net for example)

Watch out for the red triangles; these are parsing errors and will often cause the rest of the styles to be ignored by the browser.

There are two stray `}` characters in your stylesheet. You should be fine if you just delete those two lines. They can be found a few lines above the `.BlackIcon` rule, which would explain why the rule isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want like this

[image]

you  can't use

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 9999999px) {}
```

or you have to use a min-width

```css
@media only screen and ( min-width: 992px) and (max-width:99999999px) {
   .BlackIcon {
 color: Black;
 background-color: White;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 0 solid black;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: 500;
}
}
```